# Как удалить все однотипные слова из текстовой строки

Tags: c#, строки, c#-8.0

Есть строка String в которой может быть прописано свойство изменения цвета некоторых слов и это не html, **например:** `<color=#111111>Привет</color>, как <color=#fff222>дела?</color>`

**Как удалить все вхождения такого типа?**

```
<color=#111111>
<color=#fff222>
<color=#3333ff>
```

Comment: Парсить HTML правитьльно, а не изобретать свои костыли. Любой парсер имеет свойство "Текст", который отдает вам сразу сам текст, без лишних тегов ([пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UXwU4W)).

Comment: Дело в том что это не html, а обычная строка string
но ответ был полезен и для моего случая, спасибо

Comment: Так HTML это ни что иное как строка, текст.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть кому-то пригодиться, нашел лучший способ решения данной задачи, использовать регулярные выражения:

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Лучше использовать нормальный HTML парсер типа HtmlAgilityPack или AngleSharp. А регулярку эту легко сломать, если символы галочек будут встречаться не только в тегах. Другими словами, не стоит HTML парсить регулярками, это неудачное решение.